# Json.net deserialization silent error byte[]

Tags: json.net, deserialization, expandoobject

The following json is not correctly deserialized by Newtonsoft JSON.NET into byte[]:

```
{
ID:123,
Name:'test',
RowVersion: {
    $current: null,
    $current_uid: null,
    $parent_uid: 1,
    $type: "System.Byte[], mscorlib",
    $uid: 2,
    $value: "AAAAAAAAEnM="
    }
}
```

The deserialization works fine for all the members of the object except RowVersion, which is mapped to byte[] in C#, deserializes as null.

I'm using the following custom ValueProviderFactory:

```
JSONSerializer.Deserialize<List<ExpandoObject>>(JSONReader);
```

Can somebody help me understand why RowVersion is deserialized as null?

Comment: Did you try entering the keys quoted? "$value" and so...

Comment: Aside some extra properties that i added to each json object this is how Json.net delivers its data. The problem is somewhere between the ValueProviderFactory and the convesion from ExpandoObject to its type.